# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 2

Tags: music

I will give you the initials of the lyrics to the first verse of a disney song and you need to try and guess which song it is.
L A T S I I N
W Y T M C C
W Y T I T G T G W H E
L A T T T U
H M W C O C H
L A H Y T
S S G E
I G G A G A
I G W A W G
Y W T I G T
B W C N B D I W M
**Hint:**

> This song is from 1989

Comment: One suggestion: the hint makes it too easy since all you need to do is look for the Disney movie made that year... and there's usually only one.

Comment: OK I won't include a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Part of your world, Little Mermaid

Comment: Correct. Well done